# Prevent right click on embeded PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, embed

I have pdf's on a clients site using  tags, the client has requested that I prevent users from right clicking the document to stop them from saving the files (Yes I am aware this is foolish but they are adamant that this is what they want).

I have looked at many ways of achieving this but none seem to work (Some work put prevent scrolling).

I would also like to disable CRTL+S.

Answer (score 0):

While, as you said the approach is foolish and there are so many ways around it, for most users, you can just capture the [contextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event and use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the context menu from appearing (or provide a custom one). It's supported by all major desktop browsers, so should do what you need it to do without hindering scrolling or anything else.

For `Ctrl+S`, I've not attempted this before, but filtering the [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event may be an option (though tbh I doubt it). Other than that, I don't know of any other way to do this.

Comment: I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. `<body>

    <embed src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf#toolbar=0" id="noContextMenu"
        width="400px" height="600px" />

</body>
<script>
    const noContext = document.getElementById('noContextMenu');

    noContext.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>`

Comment: oh, ok. it seems this is not possible with embeds, and only possible with iframes that are served from the same domain. I'm not sure what your requirements are, but it seems these are the limitations because of browser security.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might have been the case. Appreciate your help.